# Kotlin error on selected image from gallery

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I can not load the selected image. is loading the default template image. I edited it with the complete fragment code in the post, could you guide me which parameter to use to upload to the selected image?

The following updated code works but only uploads the pre-defined image, I can not upload the selected image, I do not know which parameter to use on that line

if (this.imageUri != imageUri && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

```
class  ReportFragment : Fragment(), OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener {
    private var mMapView: MapView? = null
    private var map: GoogleMap? = null
    val CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 0
    val CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 10
    lateinit var imageFilePath: String
    private var imgThumb: ImageView? = null
    private var spinner: Spinner? = null
    private var currentLocation: LatLng? = null  // TODO: get current location as static variable
    private var midLatLng: LatLng? = null
    private var lat: Double? = null
    private var lng: Double? = null
    private var objectValues: Array<String>? = null
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private var pictureTaken: Boolean = false
    private var progress: ProgressBar? = null
    val PERMISSION_CODE_READ = 1001
    val PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE = 1002
    val IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1000
    private val database: FirebaseDatabase? = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
    private val markersRef: DatabaseReference? = database!!.getReference("markers")
    private val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    private val storageRef: StorageReference = storage.reference
    private var imagesRef: StorageReference? = null
    private val permissoes = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    inner class GenericFileProvider : FileProvider()


    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.context,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        Permissoes.validarPermissoes(permissoes, this.activity, 1)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_report, container, false)

        if (arguments != null && arguments.getDouble("lat") != null) {
            this.lat = arguments.getDouble("lat")
            this.lng = arguments.getDouble("lng")
        }
        this.objectValues = resources.getStringArray(R.array.object_values) // for dropdown

        // TODO       this.currentLocation = Utils.currentLocation
        this.progress = view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar) as ProgressBar

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        try {
            initMap(view, savedInstanceState)
        } catch (e: GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        this.imgThumb = view.findViewById(R.id.takePictureThumbnail) as ImageButton
        val camBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.takePictureBtn) as ImageButton
        val createBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.createIssueBtn) as Button
        camBtn.setOnClickListener{
            pickImageFromGallery()
        }
        this.imgThumb!!.setOnClickListener{
            takePicture()
        }

        this.spinner = view.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.object_types_spinner)
        // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.object_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
        // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        this.spinner!!.adapter = adapter

        createBtn.setOnClickListener{
            createIssue(view)
        }

        return view
    }

    fun createIssue(view: View) {
        this.progress!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        val layout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.reportLinearLayout)
        layout.alpha = 0.4f

        val random = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val imgUrl = "images/issue$random+.jpg"
        val name = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.issueNameEditText).text.toString()
        val desc = view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.issueDescriptionEditText).text.toString()
        val type = this.objectValues!![this.spinner!!.selectedItemPosition]
        var issue = Issue(name, type, this.midLatLng!!.latitude, this.midLatLng!!.longitude, desc, imgUrl, null)

        this.imagesRef = storageRef.child(imgUrl)

        var uploadTask: UploadTask = this.imagesRef!!.putBytes(putImgToBytearray())

        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
            this.progress!!.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(context,"upload Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            markersRef!!.child(random).setValue(issue)
            goToDetailsView(issue)
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            this.progress!!.visibility = View.GONE
            Toast.makeText(context,"upload failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }.addOnProgressListener {
            var prog: Double  = (100.0 * it.bytesTransferred )/ it.totalByteCount
            Log.i("transfer", prog.toString())
            //this.progress!!.setProgress(prog.toInt(), true)
        }
    }

    private fun goToDetailsView(issue: Issue) {
        val args = Bundle()

        val detailsFragment = IssueDetailsFragment()
        args.putDouble("lat", issue.lat)
        args.putDouble("lng", issue.lng)
        args.putString("description", issue.description)
        args.putString("name", issue.name)
        args.putString("type", issue.type)
        args.putString("imgUrl", issue.imgUrl)

        detailsFragment.arguments = args
        val ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        ft.replace(R.id.main_fragment_content, detailsFragment)
                .setTransition(android.app.FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .addToBackStack(null).commit()
    }
    private fun putImgToBytearray(): ByteArray {
        val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val drawable = this.imgThumb!!.drawable as BitmapDrawable
        val bitmap = drawable.bitmap
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, stream)
        return stream.toByteArray()
    }

    private fun initMap(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(this.activity)
        mMapView = view.findViewById(R.id.mapView)
        mMapView!!.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mMapView!!.onResume() //without this, map showed but was empty
        mMapView!!.getMapAsync(this)
    }
    override fun onMapClick(latLan: LatLng) {
        this.map!!.addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(latLan).title("Marker"))
    }

    /**
     * Open a camera activity with the picture returned as a result to onActivityResult
     */
    fun openCamera() {
        try {
            val imageFile = createImageFile()
            val callCameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            if(callCameraIntent.resolveActivity(activity.packageManager) != null) {
                val authorities = activity.packageName + ".fileprovider"
                this.imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, authorities, imageFile)
                callCameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
                startActivityForResult(callCameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Could not create file!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    /**
     * take a picture but check for camera permissions first
     */
    fun takePicture() {
        val permissionGranted = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        if  (permissionGranted) {
            openCamera()
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA), CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        }
    }
    private fun checkPermissionForImage() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if ((checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
                    && (checkSelfPermission(this.context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED)
            ) {
                val permission = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                val permissionCoarse = arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

                requestPermissions(permission, PERMISSION_CODE_READ) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR PERMISSION_CODE_READ LIKE 1001
                requestPermissions(permissionCoarse, PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR PERMISSION_CODE_WRITE LIKE 1002
            } else {
                pickImageFromGallery()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE ) // GIVE AN INTEGER VALUE FOR IMAGE_PICK_CODE LIKE 1000
    }

    /**
     * Open the camera after obtaining the permission
     */
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
        when (requestCode) {
            CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                if (grantResults.isEmpty() || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i("CAMERA", "Permission has been denied by user")
                } else {
                    openCamera()
                    Log.i("CAMERA", "Permission has been granted by user")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Save the picture to the thumbnail after taking it
     */
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (this.imageUri != imageUri && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


            try {
                pickImageFromGallery()
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
                this.imgThumb!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                this.pictureTaken = true
            } catch (e:IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(Date())
        val imageFileName: String = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_"
        val storageDir: File = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        if(!storageDir.exists()) storageDir.mkdirs()
        val imageFile = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir)
        imageFilePath = imageFile.absolutePath
        return imageFile
    }

    /**
     * update the the coordinated of the map center when moving the map
     */
    override fun onCameraIdle() {
        this.midLatLng = this.map!!.cameraPosition.target
    }

    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap?) {
        this.map = googleMap
        this.map!!.setOnCameraIdleListener(this)
        this.map!!.setOnMapClickListener(this)
        if (this.lat != null) {
            this.map!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LatLng(this.lat!!, this.lng!!), 8f))
        } else if(this.currentLocation != null) { // TODO
            this.map!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(this.currentLocation, 8f))
        } else {
            this.map!!.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(Utils.vienna, 8f)) // Vienna
        }
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mMapView!!.onResume()
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        mMapView!!.onStart()
    }
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mMapView!!.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mMapView!!.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView!!.onLowMemory();
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        mMapView!!.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
    }

}// Required empty public constructor
```

Comment: Can you add the complete log

Comment: @JitendraA I added the error log, please check. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a null pointer exception. imageUri is null

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
```

If you check the implementation of getBitmap().

See

```
public static final Bitmap getBitmap(ContentResolver cr, Uri url)
                throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
            InputStream input = cr.openInputStream(url);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            input.close();
            return bitmap;
        }
```

You will find that it calls the openInputStream() which requires a not null uri.

```
public final @Nullable InputStream openInputStream(@NonNull Uri uri)


   override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (this.imageUri != null && requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            try {
                //Getting the Bitmap from Gallery
                val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.contentResolver, this.imageUri) as Bitmap
                this.imgThumb!!.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
                this.pictureTaken = true
            } catch (e:IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error loading image", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to make sure that imageUri is set properly and just put a null check here

Comment: Ok, thank you, app does not break but unfortunately it does not load the image, it does not present any errors, what can be happening?

Comment: You need to fix the part where you are setting the value of imageUri. See why its null.

Comment: I can not load the selected image. is loading the default template image. I edited it with the complete fragment code in the post, could you guide me which parameter to use to upload to the selected image?

Comment: @Jitenda A code updated at post,Sorry to bother you